# how to add image

Tags: jquery, html

I have to add static header image to simple html page ,which has two div tags -

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1 /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
            <title>mysite</title>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2-min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="site.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="header.jpg"/> ----> this image is not working 
        <div id="site"></div>
        <div id="doc" class="documents"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

two div tags working fine ..but i can't see image

Comment: What is your directory structure? The image must be on the same folder of your html file with that `src`

Comment: Looks fine but as BrunoLM says the path to the image may be wrong...unless your css file is hiding images with display:none which is I think is unlikely.

Comment: yes,image at the same place where i have html file...thanks..guys for the hints I'll check css file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put static image into another div tag.. like this

```
<body>
    <div id="static"> <img src="header.jpg"/> <div>
    <div id="site"></div>
    <div id="doc" class="documents"></div>
```

and Note that your image must be on the same directory